# What is the set of observables of a quantum system?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, quantum-interpretations, observables, foundations

This is a question I am wondering about because the answer to it seems to have some interesting - but perhaps already long considered and dismissed because it's been settled - implications for the measurement problem and question of what the "best" interpretation is of the formalism of quantum theory. Yet it may seem oddly elementary to ask.

Of course, I know that observables in quantum theory are Hermitian operators on a Hilbert space, but my question is: given a quantum system, ***what* set of Hermitian operators correspond to its observables?** The reason I ask this is that there are arguments, such as those in this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OmaSAG4J6nw

that the Hilbert space can be considered in some sense a term that contains redundancy similar to a gauge theory, and that what "really matters" is the observables and associated probabilities around measuring them, which are taken as forming a structure called a *C*-algebra.*

Now, if we take that view, and the "observables come first", it suggests that the set of observables is something we define in advance, and then the Hilbert space comes later as a sort of "model" thereof (in a sense close to the one used in mathematics, where we talk of a "model of a set of axioms"). However, I also have seen in other places people saying something different: that the set of observables is *all* Hermitian operators on a Hilbert space. That is, you make a Hilbert space, then boom, you get the set of observables.

And the thing is: these two things are **not** equivalent. C*-algebras are not in one-to-one correspondence with Hilbert spaces: instead, they may be isomorphic to *proper subsets* of the sets of all Hermitian operators on a given Hilbert space.

And to top it all off, textbooks often seem to gloss over this point: many often only say that observables are Hermitian operators, then go on to introduce some (e.g. position, momentum, etc.), but "are Hermitian operators" does not imply its converse, any more than "cars are machines" implies "machines are cars".

**Is there a consensus on which view is the correct one, and if so, what is it, and why is the other one considered wrong?**

---

You may ask as to what this has to do with the measurement problem. I've asked here earlier regarding Schrodinger's cat and Wigner's friend, and this is why. **If** it is the case that the set of observables of a system is *not* necessarily comprehensive of that on some Hilbert space, then there is a very natural interpretation of quantum states as being knowledge states, that goes like this.

Consider a Wigner's friend set up, and think about the experience of both Wigner and his friend. The friend is shut in a Schrodinger cat box with a quantum experiment. He runs the experiment and sees the result. Wigner then opens the box and asks the friend and the friend replies. But if Wigner models the friend using quantum mechanics and the Schrodinger equation, he gets a superposition state. Under the seemingly sensible philosophical assumption that Wigner's friend and Wigner himself both are having experiences throughout this and Wigner's friend experienced a single outcome, then it is rational to say that Wigner's superposition assignment reflects his ignorance of what outcome transpired, leading to the notion the quantum state is *proximately* a state of knowledge, belief or otherwise of information on an agent's part, as opposed to a property of the system - through the two may be isomorphic in cases.

But this falls apart if Wigner can do a measurement on his friend on a basis incompatible with. Then it seems hard to avoid that the superposition has ontological character, and we have a real conundrum if we accept those philosophical assumptions about the experience.

**Yet all that goes away if, in fact, the incompatible measurement is not an observable of his friend,** which is possible if the observables of a system are primary to the Hilbert space instead of the other way around. Indeed, pretty much every paradox and no-go result in this vein - not just this one, but results like the Frauchiger-Renner paradox, too - seem to depend on agents being able to do incompatible measurements on their experiences.

I can't help but think this *must* have been considered before, because it seems just too easy. But I have had a hard time finding it and, moreover, given it is not even commonly referenced in these discussions, that there must be something trivially wrong with it. What is that?

Comment: Every Hermitian operator is certainly an observable. They might not all be *interesting* observables, but in principle, their eigenvalues are things that can be physically measured. For instance, we can define an observable which assigns to the $n$-th energy level of a harmonic oscillator the $2n+1$-th Fibonacci number, and we can measure this number. Other observables might be even more absurd or random, but they could still be measured.

Comment: The operators in a $C^*$ algebra are bounded. Most *interesting* operators (the energy or  momentum, say) are not bounded.

Comment: @Chiral Anomaly. I agree with what you say in principle -- the eigenmodes and  associted resolution of the identity are the key thing,  but surely the non-locality of operators like $e^{-tH}$ is more than an inconvenience  when  writing dowe interaction terms?

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly: field theories are outside of my comfort zone, so please take this as a serious question, not a rhetorical one: doesn't microcausality simply dictate how all the possible observables can be combined into fields, rather than restricting what the possible observables are in the first place? Meaning that any two Hermitian operators $A,B$ can be observables, but unless they commute, $\pi(u_1)=A$ and $\pi(u_2)=B$ requires the separation  of $u_1$ and $u_2$ to be time-like, if $\pi$ is a valid field?

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos In QFT, observables are expressed in terms of field ops, but the field ops themselves are not necessarily observables. Fermion field ops don't commute with each other at spacelike separations, so microcausality doesn't allow treating them as observables. If we trim the Hilbert space down so that all remaining ops qualify as observables, then it can't include states with different total electric charge (using QED as an example), which we normally prefer to do.

Comment: @mikestone Sure, I would say it's prohibitively inconvenient. But the question asks about a matter of general principle, and the way it uses ∗-algebra is appropriate/sufficient for the question being asked.

Answer (score 0):

This is a sort of mostly-answer and elaboration to the other.

As @Chiral Anomaly mentions, **the set of observables must be specified ahead of time** as part of modeling the system in question. Defining its set of observables is like defining what properties it has, as a physical object - just like not all objects have, say, the property of "having an engine" or "intelligence", likewise not all of them will have some particular weird quantum operator. Then, once a set of "basis" observables is put down, additional ones are then generated by algebraic combinations.

Thus, regarding Wigner's friend, the answer **does indeed depend on how we model the friend**:

1. If we attribute it *only* the property "what did it see?", then we have no contradiction as to when Wigner ascribes it the entangled-superposition state, that in an information-based interpretation of the quantum state, this *could* mean the friend did indeed see an outcome but the Schrodinger equation that Wigner used to obtain it simply isn't good enough to predict the actual outcome.
2. *But if* we now consider a friend *which does have* a *complementary* (incompatible) property to the above, then we run into difficulties. If the "what-see" property was decided by this point, then Wigner presuambly could determine this by doing an ensemble measurement upon the incompatible-with-"what-see" property, and would falsify the Schrodinger equation prediction empirically. Even if Wigner's quantum state, to be consistent, should still be taken *proximally* as knowledge, in this situation it seems to hold more "objective weight" because it tells him something is tangibly different in this case.

Yet the Schrodinger equation has never been seen to be falsified empirically. This suggests either there is something conceptually wrong with quantum theory and/or how we are applying it in the situation described (e.g. maybe there is an extra nonlinear governing law, e.g. GRW theory, or there are some sort of exotic hidden variables, or ...), *or* that real friends don't have properties incompatible to their "experience" property. Discussion (and production of no-go theorems and results) mostly centers around the first outlet - interestingly, I have not seen much mention of the second outlet, even to argue for its falsity. And that was what I was hoping to gain with this question - has that prong both been addressed and is so widely-known as so that it never needs to be, or has something been overlooked here, perhaps because of how quantum theory has been taught or propagated? I still have no answer for that.

Comment: Based on the comments and on the self-answer, it seems that I misunderstood the question. This answer says: "I have not seen much mention of the second outlet... And that was what I was hoping to gain with this question..." Can you clarify which option you mean by "second outlet"? (Is the first "and/or" meant to separate two different outlets? Or are those two different parts of the first outlet?)

Comment: @Chiral Anomaly: You are correct in your assessment that part of this question is about what the observable set constitutes. However, the other part of the question is that this _seems_ to have bearing on interpretational issues for the mathematical formalism, and I want to know if there is something there, or it's long been known to be irrelevant for some reason and, if so, what that reason is and what I am just missing as a result of ignorance and naivete.

Comment: And the second part actually inspires the first, because part of what I'm wondering if I'm getting wrong is that there is in fact good reason to assume that the whole Hermitian set is theoretically observable, and thus we have a genuine problem when it comes to things like Wigner's friend. Because if it is not, then it seems that if only the quantum system in the setup has noncommuting parameters but the friend's "experience parameter" has no other incompatible parameter, there is a straightforward solution, but if the friend _does_ have such a parameter, then things indeed become problematic.

Comment: And what I'm asking about is if this has even been observed or remarked upon somewhere and if it has, I'd be curious to read about that. If we are indeed deciding observables by modelling, then it seems intuitive at least to me that if we're going to posit Wigner's friend, we'd "naturally" only include for the sake of such an observable corresponding to "I saw a '0'/'1'". And if we do that, Wigner can just interpret his quantum state assignment as a knowledge state and the superposition as merely reflective of his ignorance.

Comment: However, if we adduce an incompatible observable (parameter) into the "friend", then this situation changes and there seems to be more non-trivial meaning to the superposition and tension with the idea the "friend" saw an outcome. (Which of course, then, suggests another idea: maybe a friend with incompatible parameters to its "experience" and a friend without them _are different kinds of beasts_ and we aren't philosophically justified in imputing to the former the same kind of "experience" as the latter.)

Comment: The thing is, to me, this possibility seems so - i.e. too - simple that I can't believe it has been somehow overlooked and I don't wanna just assume that maybe I stumbled on something interesting here when I didn't. I'm extremely skeptical of this and so I think it has to be wrong somehow.

Comment: Regarding whether this has ever been noticed before, the answer is yes. The idea that many of the operators we formally call observables are not actually measurable in practice is well-known. The problem is that we can't turn that into to a *natural* refinement of the set of operators we call observables. Even quantifying it is difficult: the Omnès book that I cited is one of the few attempts I've seen, and it's the only one for which I recall the specific reference right now. Many authors have commented about it in passing, but I haven't kept track because they're not saying anything new.

Comment: So, instead of baking an artificial threshold into the theory, we might as well leave it unspecified and use loose intuition to judge each observable's measurability, case-by-case, like we've always implicitly done. The fact that we don't know how to promote that loose intuition to a mathematically-natural postulate is the content of the Wigner's-friend paradox. Loose intuition can't solve the paradox, because the fact that the intuition is loose is the whole point of the paradox. I think the thoughts you're expressing are consistent with this, if I understand them correctly.

Comment: The paper [arXiv:1105.3796](https://arxiv.org/abs/1105.3796) actually appeals to *cosmology* to try to address the issue. That feels to me like an act of desperation, but on the other hand, spacetime is emergent in quantum gravity, so maybe appealing to far-away conditions to address a close-to-home paradox isn't as completely crazy as it sounds -- at least in the context of a full theory of quantum gravity, which is [out of my league](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/out%20of%20one%27s%20league).

Comment: @Chiral Anomaly : Thanks. The point I think I was after is in if there is recognized a distinction between the two _types of_ (theoretical) observer: the one that has an incompatible property against its "experiential property" and the one that doesn't - regardless of if/how we can identify or not such. I do not know that this constitutes a complete answer, as you point out, because maybe "we" (or "realistic" observers) _do have_ such incompatible properties with their experiential property and then we have a real paradox.

Comment: But at the very least it seems worthwhile to remark there is no paradox until such a property is posited (also, if we can find and access it, that'd open the potential door to _empirical_ testing of these issues), and to remark that the two types of observers exist theoretically, so that we should ask as to whether "we" or "realistic" observers can/can't be either type and what each type can/can't experience. I think that's my point.